# Column select in Mousepad?

Tags: xubuntu, text-editor, mousepad

[Mousepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce#Leafpad) is the default text editor of Xubuntu. Is there a column select mode in Mousepad? How can I enable it?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out why. Press shift+alt+ctrl + mouse click where you want to start, keep pressed the keys + click again and move the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this, the feature is absent due to migration from GTK+2 to GTK+3 this feature is yet **not available**.
More details here:

- https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/mousepad/-/issues/57
- https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/mousepad/-/issues/73

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish column-specific tasks in **Mousepad** (verified with **Mousepad** version **0.3.0**, under **Debian Jessie**; and **Mousepad** version **0.4.0**, under **Debian Stretch**):

Let's say you have three lines of text in a **Mousepad** document:

```
abcde
abcde
abcde
```

and you want to append an asterisk to the end of each line.

Select a block that *starts and ends* at the column of interest:

[image]

Next, click **Edit** -> **Change the selection**. This will give you a thin vertical line at said column of interest:

[image]

Now, type in an asterisk:

[image]

A mouse click outside of the current selection and you're done!

***FYI, casual research indicates that this feature MAY not be available in Debian Buster.***